# Can I send more than only value with v-model to v-for

Tags: vue.js

I am new to Vue but I think that this can be really useful.

I have my first problem this simplified example

```js
var appvue = new Vue({
  el: '#appvue',
  data: {
    selectedProd: []
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  
}
.form-row{
 width:24%;
 display:inline-block;
}
#appvue {
  background: #fff;
  padding:10px;
}
#prod_adjust{
  margin-top:20px;
  background: #eee
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div class="prod-wrap" id="appvue">
  <div class="form-row">
    <input v-model="selectedProd" name="product-1260" id="product-1260" type="checkbox" value="1260">
    <label for="product-1260">
      <div class="thumb">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100">
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <span class="brand">Brand 1</span>
        <span class="product-title">Product 1</span>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <input v-model="selectedProd" name="product-1261" id="product-1261" type="checkbox" value="1261">
    <label for="product-1261">
      <div class="thumb">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100">
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <span class="brand">Brand 2</span>
        <span class="product-title">Product 2</span>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <input v-model="selectedProd" name="product-1263" id="product-1263" type="checkbox" value="1263">
    <label for="product-1263">
      <div class="thumb">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100">
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <span class="brand">Brand 3</span>
        <span class="product-title">Product 3</span>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <input v-model="selectedProd" name="product-1264" id="product-1264" type="checkbox" value="1264">
    <label for="product-1264">
      <div class="thumb">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100">
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <span class="brand">Brand 4</span>
        <span class="product-title">Product 4</span>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div id="prod_adjust">
    <p v-for="product in selectedProd">{{product}}</p>
  </div>



</div>
```

I have a lot of products like the checkboxes above. I need to have the list of checked items in another place.

I did this with `v-model` and `v-for` - but my main problem is now that there are sending only the value from the checkboxes - I also need `img-src`, `brand`, `product-title` - all these parameters I also can have more attributes in an input.

But how I can pass them in data: `{ selectedProd:[]}` with Vue?

Or I do I need to create a separate JS function which will collect all this data and send it to the array `selectedProd`?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section on how to ask and then edit your question, as this will help the community better understand your specific issue and provide you with a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to create an object with the data you need for the product. Then you can use v-for to loop through and display them the way you'd like.

In the example, I included a computed function that automatically returns the ones that get checked. This is done by v-model binding the checkbox to a flag inside your object. In this example, I called it `selected`, for simplicity.

```js
var appvue = new Vue({
  el: '#appvue',
  data: {
    products: [{
      id: 1260,
      brand: "Brand A",
      product: "Bubblegun",
      image: "https://picsum.photos/100/100",
      selected: false
    }, {
      id: 1261,
      brand: "Brand B",
      product: "Bubblegum",
      image: "https://picsum.photos/100/100",
      selected: false
    }],
  },
  computed: {
    selectedProd() {
      return this.products.map(product => {
        if (product.selected) return product
      })
    }
  }

})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
}

.form-row {
  width: 24%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#appvue {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

#prod_adjust {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #eee
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div class="prod-wrap" id="appvue">
  <div class="form-row" v-for="product in products">
    <input v-model="product.selected" name="product-1260" id="product-1260" type="checkbox">
    <label for="product-1260">
    <div class="thumb">
    <img :src="product.image">
   </div>
      <div class="details">
    <span class="brand">{{product.brand}}</span>
    <span class="product-title">{{product.product}}</span>
   </div>
  </label>
  </div>

  <div id="prod_adjust">
    <p v-for="product in selectedProd">{{product}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But problem that I already have products layout and it is difficult to change. I changed a little my code. https://jsfiddle.net/maxos/rt7c5pj2/1/  My idea now in using v-model="prodids" for separate array, and after in computed just check if product id in array prodids. But this not work for me. But for example if I uncomment   (//if (1) return product), than looks that all works. I think some wrong with my checking that product.id in array (prodids) - but not sure what

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/maxos/rt7c5pj2/2/ - commented condition. in prev comment  uncommented

Answer (score 0):

If you have the input as a JSON which has all the properties you are asking for (product_ID, img src, brand name) then you can assign the object to v-model instead of product_ID.

Your JSON array should look like this,

`productsArray: [ 
    { productID: 1260,
      product-title: "Product 1",
      brand: "Brand 1",
      img: "https://picsum.photos/100/100"
    },
    { productID: 1261,
      product-title: "Product 2",
      brand: "Brand 2",
      img: "https://picsum.photos/100/100"
    },]`

Then inside `v-for` you can read each object and when selected you can assign the entire object into `selectedProd`

Answer (score 0):

I used next way finally

```
    vueproducts = function(){
    appvue.selectedProd = [];
    var tempprod = {};
    $('.form-row input').each(function(){
        if ($(this).is(":checked")){
            tempprod.id = $(this).val();
            tempprod.img = $(this).parent().find('img').attr('src');
            tempprod.title = $(this).parent().find('.product-title').html();

            appvue.selectedProd.push(tempprod);
            tempprod = {};
        };
    });
}
```